# Getting a KeyError when parsing JSON file

Tags: python, json, keyerror

I just started working with JSON files yesterday, and I've searched other questions relating to KeyError, but none of the answers have helped so far. I'm trying to parse this JSON file and create a dictionary making 'article' the key and 'views' the value. However, I just get a KeyError when trying to print it. The code works if I use a different URL, but I need to use this one. Am I just printing this wrong?

```
def display(url, text):
    print(url)
    dictionary = json.loads(text)
    for item in dictionary['items']:
        print(f"{item['article']}:\t\t{item['views']}")


def main():
    url = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikiversity/all-access/2018/01/all-days"
    display(url, text)



main()
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your input ```dictionary```, this will help other people to understand your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the actual JSON data:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "project": "en.wikiversity",
      "access": "all-access",
      "year": "2018",
      "month": "01",
      "day": "all-days",
      "articles": [
        {
          "article": "Psycholinguistics/Models_of_Speech_Production",
          "views": 585462,
          "rank": 1
        },
        {
          "article": "Wikiversity:Main_Page",
          "views": 118971,
          "rank": 2
        },
        {
          "article": "Special:Search",
          "views": 60332,
          "rank": 3
        },
```

You're not looking for `items[n]['article|views']`, you're actually looking for `items[n]['articles'][n]['article|views']`

```py
def display(url, text):
    print(url)
    dictionary = json.loads(text)
    for item in dictionary['items']:
        for article in item['articles']:
            print(f"{article['article']}:\t\t{article['views']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The is only one thing wrong with your code:

There is no `article` key on items you are iteration. Actually, there is a list of articles in it. So, if you just add:

```
for article in item['articles']:
```

It will work (change your display method):

```
def display(url, text):
    print(url)
    dictionary = json.loads(text)
    for item in dictionary['items']:
        for article in item['articles']:
            print(f"{article['article']}:\t\t{article['views']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a json viewer like in firefox to browse the json.  You're not referencing it correctly.

First, that page only has one entry in items, so iterating seems weird.

Either way, in your for loop, each item is a dict.  There is key called articles that is a list of dicts, so you'll need a nested loop.

```
def display(url, text):
    print(url)
    dictionary = json.loads(text)
    for item in dictionary['items']:
        for article in item['articles']:
            print(f"{article['article']}:\t\t{article['views']}")
```